# Better way to pick a random entry from args?

Tags: linux, bash

Was just wondering because I whipped this up last month.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Collects all of the args, make sure to seperate with ','
IN="$*"

# Takes everything before a ',' and places them each on a single line of tmp file
echo $IN | sed 's/,/\n/g' > /tmp/pick.a.random.word.or.phrase

# Obvious vars are obvious
WORDFILE="/tmp/pick.a.random.word.or.phrase"

# Pick only one of the vars
NUMWORDS=1

## Picks a random line from tmp file

#Number of lines in $WORDFILE
tL=`awk 'NF!=0 {++c} END {print c}' $WORDFILE`

# Expand random
RANDOM_CMD='od -vAn -N4 -tu4 /dev/urandom'

for i in `seq $NUMWORDS`
do
rnum=$((`${RANDOM_CMD}`%$tL+1))
sed -n "$rnum p" $WORDFILE | tr '\n' ' '

done

printf "\n"

rm /tmp/pick.a.random.word.or.phrase
```

Mainly I ask:

1. Do I need to have a tmp file?
2. Is there a way to do this in one line with another program?
3. How to condense as much as possible?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you invoke the command?  It isn't clear where the commas figure in the description.

Comment: btw, the pattern you're using with `RANDOM_CMD` is prone to some serious bugs -- it won't deal correctly with commands containing literal quotes, escaped whitespace, etc; see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a description of the relevant best-practice.

Comment: You also might consider replacing the (nonstandardized) `seq` command with the bash-builtin `for (( i=0; i<NUMWORDS; i++))` C-style `for` loop syntax.

Comment: Also, consider avoiding all-caps names for your own variables. See POSIX guidelines at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph -- all-caps environment variables are used by the shell and operating system; using lowercase names for your own variables prevents overwriting ones that change system behavior by mistake. (Relevant for non-exported shell variables because if an environment variable already exists with the same name, setting a shell variable by that name will overwrite it).

Comment: ...in general, btw, try to avoid `$*` -- it loses the difference between the two arguments `./cmd foo bar` and the single argument `./cmd "foo bar"`. The right way to store an argument list is in a shell-native array, which will let you preserve the distinction: `in=( "$@" )`, thereafter `${in[0]}`, `${in[1]}` to get elements by index, `${#in[@]}` to get its length, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The command-line argument handling is, to my mind, bizarre. Why not just use normal command line arguments? That makes the problem trivial:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
shuf -en1 "$@"
```

Of course, you could just use `shuf -en1`, which is only nine keystrokes:

```
$ shuf -en1 word another_word "random phrase"
another_word
$ shuf -en1 word another_word "random phrase"
word
$ shuf -en1 word another_word "random phrase"
another_word
$ shuf -en1 word another_word "random phrase"
random phrase
```

`shuf` command-line flags:

```
-e    Shuffle command line arguments instead of lines in a file/stdin
-n1   Produce only the first random line (or argument in this case)
```

If you really insist on running the arguments together and then separating them with commas, you can use the following. As with your original, it will exhibit unexpected behaviour if some word in the arguments could be glob-expanded, so I really don't recommend it:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
IFS=, read -ra args <<<"$*"
echo $(shuf -en1 "${args[@]}")
```

The first line combines the arguments and then splits the result at commas into the array `args`. (The `-a` option to read.) Since the string is split at commas, spaces (such as though automatically inserted by the argument concatenation) are preserved; to remove the spaces, I word-split the result of `shuf` by not quoting the command expansion.

Comment: @charles: i was trying to mimic the behaviour in the OP, which I already described as "bizarre". Leaving out the quotes was deliberate but, as you say, accident-prone.

Comment: Ahh, right. Suppose you might use `set -f` to disable globbing, but then, the OP's code did expand globs... might just extend the answer ("If you really insist on running the arguments together, separating them with commas, and expanding each post-separation value as a glob")

Comment: Thanks I had no idea there was a program called `shuf` so that answers question #2 right there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [shuff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf) to shorten your script and remove temporary file.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Collects all of the args, make sure to seperate with ','
IN="$*"

# Takes everything before a ',' and places them in an array
words=($(echo $IN | sed 's/,/ /g'))

# Get random indexi in range: 0, length of array: words
index=$(shuf -i 0-"${#words[@]}" -n 1)

# Print the random index
echo ${words[$index]}
```

If you don't want to use shuff, you could also use `$RANDOM`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Collects all of the args, make sure to seperate with ','
IN="$*"

# Takes everything before a ',' and places them in an array
words=($(echo $IN | sed 's/,/ /g'))

# Print the random index
echo ${words[$RANDOM % ${#words[@]}]}
```

Comment: ${#words} is always 1. it should be ${#words[@]}

Comment: @frangio: `${#words}` is not always 1. It is the length in characters of `$words`; if `words` is an array, `$words` is the array's first element.

Comment: Thanks I had no idea there was a program called `shuf` so that answers question #2 right there.

Answer (score 0):

[`shuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf) in coreutils does exactly this, but with multiple command arguments instead of a single comma separated argument.

```
shuf -n1 -e arg1 arg2 ...
```

The `-n1` option says to choose just one element. The `-e` option indicates that elements will be passed as arguments (as opposed to through standard input).

Your script then just needs to replace commas with spaces in `$*`. We can do this using bash parameter substitution:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
shuf -n1 -e ${*//,/ }
```

This won't work with elements with embedded spaces.

Comment: Why not `shuf -n1 -e "$@"`? That way you have no problems with embedded spaces (or globs -- `*` would then put the name of every file in the current directory into the set of things being shuffled)

Comment: Yeah that's definitely the right thing to do, I just stuck to the OP's format

Comment: This goes to show that I realllllllly need to read the entire coreutils manual pages

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it as simple as generating a number at random between 1 and `$#` and simply echo the corresponding argument?  It depends on what you have; your comment about 'collect arguments; make sure to separate with commas' isn't clear, because the assignment does nothing with commas — and you don't show how you invoke your command.

I've simply cribbed the random number generation from the question: it works OK on my Mac, generating the values 42,405,691 and 1,817,261,076 on successive runs.

```
n=$(( $(od -vAn -N4 -tu4 /dev/urandom) % $# + 1 ))
eval echo "\${$n}"
```

You could even reduce that to a single line if you were really determined:

```
eval echo "\${$(( $(od -vAn -N4 -tu4 /dev/urandom) % $# + 1 ))}"
```

This use of `eval` is safe as it involves no user input.  The script should check that it is provided at least one argument to prevent a division-by-zero error if `$#` is 0.  The code does an absolute minimum of data movement — in contrast to solutions which shuffle the data in some way.

If that's packaged in a script `random_selection`, then I can run:

```
$ bash random_selection Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
Feb
$ bash random_selection Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
Oct
$ bash random_selection Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
Nov
$
```

If the total number of arguments is big enough that you run out of argument space, then you need to think again, but that restriction is present in the existing code.

The selection is marginally biassed towards the earlier entries in the list; you have to do a better job of rejecting random numbers that are very near the maximum value in the range.  For a random 32-bit unsigned value, if it is larger than `$# * (0xFFFFFFFF / $#)` you should generate another random number.